# Cron job to run a php script for 24 hours then stop it

Tags: php, cron

Is it possible with cron tab(job) to run `.php` script every sunday at 0:01h till 23:59h? The main idea is at Sunday 0:01h to run this script which will place some text on the websait. This text will stay there for 24 hours and at 23:59h to stop the script and hide the text?
Any ideas how can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 0 * * 0     /usr/bin/php myScriptThatCreatesContent.php
59 23 * * 0   /usr/bin/php myScriptThatRemovesContent.php
```

[See Cron format reference here](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm), taking into account that most implementations only use 5 fields (year not supported).

The formats above specify minutes and hour and day-of-week, which can occur on any day of month in any month (the 2 stars). The 0 at the end is the first day of the week, which is Sunday for crons.

Comment: The last `0` is for a day? So for Sunday I need to put `7` on both start and stop script? I will execute this every Sunday..

Comment: It's the DOW (Day Of Week) value. 0 is Sunday, 6 is Saturday.